# Connect to wifi on boot

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

So I installed ubuntu server on my laptop.
I connected to my wifi by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`, and adding following:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid MyNetworkSSID
wpa-psk MyPassword
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

then I used `sudo ifup wlan0` and everything worked fine.
The problem is that after I restarted my computer I am no longer able to connect my wifi using `sudo ifup -v wlan0` and it also does not connect to it on boot. I also tried to replace `iface wlan0 inet static` with `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` but this changed nothing. When Im using `sudo ifup -v wlan0` I am getting `ifup: interface wlan0 already configured`.

I tried to find something on google but I found no results that would help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it working by editing /etc/rc.local and adding following:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup -v wlan0 --force
```

above `exit 0`.

Answer (score 0):

First stop network-manager i hate that thing

```
sudo service network-manager stop

wpa_passphrase "SSID" password > /etc/deadpooliscool.conf
```

and

```
 service network-manager stop

 wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/deadpooliscool.conf -Dwext && dhclient -r wlan0 && dhclient wlan0 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

add these lines to /etc/rc.local above exit 0

and your good to go.

Comment: I checked out services and I have no `network-manager` I got `networking` therefor i let myself to skip stopping network-manager, however adding `wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/deadpooliscool.conf -Dwext && dhclient -r wlan0 && dhclient wlan0 > /dev/null 2>&1` to /etc/rc.local changed nothing, computer still did not connected to wifi after reboot, also system stuck at turning on ssh server and it took about 2 minutes to turn on tty1, while all other tty's worked perfectly

Comment: some problem with the driver i presume but i glad your problem was solved